# firefox browse file dialog show wrong filter

Tags: html, firefox, input

I have a simple file upload input that accepts image/jpeg
For some reason when Firefox open the browse file dialog, it filters files as "image/jpeg (*.jfif)
Then I am unable to pick .jpg/.jpeg files (it is looking for .jfif files )

[image]

Firefox is 54.0.1 (32-bit)

```html
<input id="fileData" name="fileData" type="file" accept="image/jpeg" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same question... Firefox bug? (It works with Chromium/IE/Opera).

**Workaround:** use extension instead of MIME type:

```html
<input id="fileData" name="fileData" type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg" />
```